# Replace image pixel color on condition in Python

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, replace

I have an RGBA image where I have to find if any pixel has red value < 150 and to replace such pixels to black. I am using following code for this:

```
import numpy as np
imgarr = np.array(img)
for x in range(imgarr.shape[0]):
    for y in range(imgarr.shape[1]):
        if imgarr[x, y][0] < 150:    # red value < 150
            imgarr[x, y] = (0,0,0,255)
```

However, this is a slow loop and I am sure it can be optimized using some function such as [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), but I am not able to fit it in this code. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with the mask of comparison against the threshold -

```
img = np.asarray(img)
imgarr = np.where(img[...,[0]]<150,(0,0,0,255),img)
```

We are using `img[...,[0]]` to keep the number of dims as needed for broadcasted assignment with `np.where`. So, another way would be to use `img[...,0,None]<150` to get the mask that keeps dims.

Comment: Use of `...` and `[0]` and `0,None` in arrays is interesting. Is there a good link to learn more about these?

Comment: @rnso This should help out - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing

Comment: In the `np.where` argument, it should be `imgarr` and not `img` (at both places).

Comment: @rnso Yeah I assumed `img` to be an array. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

For one channel image, we can do as follow

```
out_val = 0
gray = cv2.imread("colour.png",0)

gray[gray<value] = out_val
```